# Blender Geometry Nodes: Make Instances Real infinite loading

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, instances

I used Geometry Nodes to populate an area of my landscape with trees. Now I need to make those tree instances real to export as gltf for the web (Object -> Apply -> Make Instances Real). When I do that my blender starts loading infinitely and I have to force close it.

Here is my Geometry Node setup. I had to decrease the Density Factor to a really small number (0.001). Otherwise Blender crashed already at this point. Strangely it generates about 7'200 trees even though the number is that small.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be?

Thanks in advance

**Other Information**

- The landscape is quite big: 9000m x 10000m x 1923m
- Total Vertices: 18'721
- I use a M1 Max with 32GB of RAM

[image]

Comment: That's totally "normal" because the realize instance node makes real geometry from just "copies" before. So depending on your tree size of course your blend file will "blow" up. There is no "easy" way to change this. One idea is camera culling (just realize tree where the camera can see them), other idea is having different detailed trees depending on camera distance: low poly far away, high poly just near cam. Some mid-poly trees in between.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually the trees are already low-poly with about 240 verticies per tree. I just tried to use simple cubes instead of trees to populate the landscape and the problem still exists. I think there is another problem since 7'200 cubes shouldn't "blow up" the system.

Comment: then u should provide your blend file so that we can check it out.

Comment: Just added it via Blend-Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly found a solution which worked

I had to use a *Collection Info* instead of *Object Info* in Geometry Nodes and remove the *Join Geometry* node at the end. With this workflow the mesh for each tree is shared, which is what I tried to accomplish.

[image]